# How does this paper published in 3 months before the filing date affect the claims?

Tags: prior-art, ep2155766a1

I found patent [EP 2155766 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP2155766A1) while looking at Ru mediators. I also found [this paper](http://lbms03.cityu.edu.hk/theses/abt/mphil-bch-b22687452a.pdf), published April 2008, 3 months before the filing date.

Does this invalidate the patent?

Answer (score 2):

The patent document you cite is an application, not a granted European patent. The U.S. counterpart is [2011/0262950](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110262950). It received a non final rejection that was responded to in April 2013. I do not see the paper you cite listed by the applicant or the examiner but there is a paper by Chen et al in 1985 in Inorganic Chemistry used to reject many of the claims. I found this information in the publicly available database - [USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair/). I do not know enough chemistry to comment on the substance.